# C++ CreateFile() function confusing me

Tags: c++, winapi

Can anyone please tell me why it won't create the `´´´test.bat´´´` in Documents folder? I've used `HRESULT hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, 0, NULL, &path);` to find the path to Documents folder. Then added the `\\test.bat`to it. When I change the `CreateFile(filePath,` to `CreateFile(L"Path to documents",` it create the file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <KnownFolders.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <ShlObj.h>
#include <atlstr.h>

using namespace std; 


int main()
{
    char str[] = "@echo off\n echo Hello\n pause";
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(str);
    DWORD dwBytesRead;
    char buff[4096];
    PWSTR path = NULL;
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    HRESULT hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Documents, 0, NULL, &path);
    string pathStart = CW2A(path);
    string file = pathStart + "\\test.bat";
    LPCWSTR filePath;
    filePath = (LPCWSTR)file.c_str();
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {   
        //cout << file << endl;
        HANDLE mFile = CreateFile(filePath, GENERIC_ALL, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN, NULL);
        WriteFile(mFile, str, dwBytesToWrite, NULL, NULL);
        if (ReadFile(mFile, buff, 4096, &dwBytesRead, NULL))
        {
            cout << "Succes! Filen er skrevet!" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Fejl! Filen blev ikke skrevet!" << endl;
        }

    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `sizeof("\\\\")` will be 3, this is probably not what you want

Comment: That's **a lot of code** for a question with this title. Please consider providing a proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the issue you are facing.

Comment: It should replace all the "\" with "\\" so the file can be created.. But I can't figure it out..

Comment: You are mistaken - you do **not** need to replace a single backslash with a pair of backslashes. You only need to double up the backslashes in a string literal embedded in the source code - not in a string generated programmatically. Drop `pathStart.replace(...)` line.

Comment: `filePath = (LPCWSTR)file.c_str();` This ain't gonna work. Casting a pointer doesn't magically turn an ANSI string into a Unicode string. You already know about `CW2A` - look up the counterpart. Better still, use `wstring` in place of `string`, thus staying with Unicode throughout and avoiding conversions altogether.

Comment: as igor says - you are confusing escaping string (and how debuggers display \) with what actually needs to be there in the string. You only need single \

Comment: Okay thanks.. I got it to work. I have found out that if I take change the FOLDERID_Startup to FOLDERID_Desktop it creates the file. It need some permissions to create a file there. How do i grant them?

Comment: I don't need to replace anything. I just need to add the "\\test.bat" and it works. It can create the file on the desktop but not in the startup folder

Comment: That's a completely different question. Although I hope the answer is "no"; random programs shouldn't be adding things to Startup. Try running your program as Administrator?

Comment: PLEASE SUBMIT A NEW QUESTION. Its totally misleading to paste an entirely new question since all the comments and answers look random now

Comment: but any way - why not test the result of createfile and writefile.

Comment: I dont think you can cast a string.c_str to LPWCSTR and hope it just works, You need wstring, or the opposite of CW2A

Comment: It says `"no suitable conversion function from std::wstring to LPCWSTR exists"`

Answer (score 0):

1. You are replacing three characters (`sizeof("\\\\")` - don't forget the null terminator! `strlen` would have been closer but that's still two, not one), which means the `\`, the `U` and the `s`
2. You're only replacing the first match, so only the first `\` will be replaced
3. You shouldn't be replacing anything anyway. Just leave the slashes as they are.

We escape backslashes in string literals (and *only* string literals — that means bits of your *source code* that look like `"this"`) so as to indicate that they themselves do not introduce an escape sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This `LPSTR pst = &myString[0];  // get temporary LPSTR, not very safe` Was the thing. It solved the problem.